# Get state but want country in GeoPy and Nominatim

Tags: python, geocoding, nominatim, geopy, georgia

I use the geopy library in Python to find the location of countries. I use country names as input,  like:

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="anonymous@gmail.com")    
geolocator.geocode("Georgia")
```

The output: `(32.3293809, -83.1137366)`

But this is de longitude and latitude of the state Georgia and not the country Georgia.

I tried: `geolocator.geocode(country="Georgia")`, but that doesn't seem to work; no output.

How do I get the country instead of the state? Am I missing a parameter?

Comment: Try to use its name in another language. For example, their names are Gürcistan(country), Georgia(state) in Turkish.

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz This worked thanks!

Comment: @Taras using country_codes worked too, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Taras Put your comment in the answer, it might help others with similar problem.

Comment: @Taras Thanks again!

Comment: https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you try embedding `exactly_one=False` parameter (by default it is `True`) into your code, like

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='anonymous@gmail.com', timeout=10)
location = geolocator.geocode("Georgia", exactly_one=False)
```

the result will be a list, where you can observe that `10` OSM-features possess `'Georgia'` string in it.

> [Location(Georgia, United States of America, (32.3293809, -83.1137366,
> 0.0)), Location(საქართველო, (41.6809707, 44.0287382, 0.0)), Location(Georgia, Franklin County, Vermont, United States of America,
> (44.72422295, -73.14704151731551, 0.0)), Location(Georgia, Freehold
> Township, New Jersey, 07710, United States of America, (40.1873348,
> -74.2845906, 0.0)), Location(Georgia, Lawrence County, Indiana, United States of America, (38.7100521, -86.5722154, 0.0)), Location(Georgia,
> Lamar County, Texas, United States of America, (33.7539902,
> -95.8313566, 0.0)), Location(Georgia, Hartselle, Morgan County, Alabama, 35640, United States of America, (34.453428, -86.9280617,
> 0.0)), Location(Georgia, Kingman County, Kansas, 67067, United States of America, (37.6277929, -98.008669, 0.0)), Location(Georgia,
> Assumption Parish, Louisiana, 70372, United States of America,
> (29.8402049, -90.9884312, 0.0)), Location(Georgia, دبي, United Arab
> Emirates, (25.20796335, 55.153055200000004, 0.0))]

When `geolocator.geocode("Georgia")` is used, it it results in a first element from the list, i.e. `Location(Georgia, United States of America, (32.3293809, -83.1137366, 0.0))`.

So, there are several solutions to achieve country instead of a state.

1. Using `country_codes="ge"` parameter, a list with two-letter country codes can be found in [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2)

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='anonymous@gmail.com', timeout=10)
location = geolocator.geocode("Georgia", country_codes="ge")
```

2. Using country name written in a native language, e.g. for [Georgia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Georgia_(country)) both `'საქართველო'` or `'Sakartvelo'`

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='anonymous@gmail.com', timeout=10)
location = geolocator.geocode("საქართველო")
```

or

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='anonymous@gmail.com', timeout=10)
location = geolocator.geocode("Sakartvelo")
```

3. Using country name written in a different language, e.g. `'Грузія'` in Ukrainian. As was mentioned by @Kadir Şahbaz in his comment.

```py
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='anonymous@gmail.com', timeout=10)
location = geolocator.geocode("Грузія")
```

Result of `print(location.raw)`

> {'place_id': 235489648, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors,
> ODbL 1.0. [https://osm.org/copyright'](https://osm.org/copyright%27), 'osm_type': 'relation',
> 'osm_id': 28699, 'boundingbox': ['41.0552922', '43.5864294',
> '39.8844803', '46.7365373'], 'lat': '41.6809707', 'lon': '44.0287382',
> 'display_name': 'საქართველო', 'class': 'boundary', 'type':
> 'administrative', 'importance': 0.7384537973566208, 'icon':
> 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_boundary_administrative.p.20.png';}

---

**References:**

- [GeoPy's documentation | Nominatim](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode)

Answer (score 1):

There is also the option to specify a region to search in or even restrict results to. This should be used when ever possible and will be much safer than playing language tricks.

If you look at the [documentation of the method](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode), you can see the parameters `viewbox` and `bounded`.

```
viewbox (list or tuple of 2 items of geopy.point.Point or 
        (latitude, longitude) or "%(latitude)s, %(longitude)s".)
        – Coordinates to restrict search within.
        Example: [Point(22, 180), Point(-22, -180)].

bounded (bool) – Restrict the results to only items contained 
        within the bounding view_box.
```

Right now the documentation is a bit out of date, `viewbox` is actually just a *hint*.

So to ask Nominatim to prefer results in the area of Georgia the Country, you could do this:

```
>>> geolocator.geocode("Georgia", viewbox=((40, 39), (44, 47)))
Location(საქართველო, (41.6809707, 44.0287382, 0.0))
```

And if you want to make sure that nothing from elsewhere is returned, you would also include the `bounded` parameter:

```
>>> geolocator.geocode(
>>>         "Georgia",
>>>         viewbox=((40, 39), (44, 47)), 
>>>         bounded=True
>>> )
Location(საქართველო, (41.6809707, 44.0287382, 0.0))
```