# Getting list of result from GeoPy Nominatim

Tags: python, nominatim, geopy

How can I get list of possible result in Nominatim?

My code is

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_email@myserver.com")
location = geolocator.geocode("School")
location.raw
```

but unfortunately it only shows one result

```
geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="my_email@myserver.com")

location = geolocator.geocode("School")

location.raw

{'place_id': 174509566,
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
 'osm_type': 'way',
 'osm_id': 353533683,
 'boundingbox': ['35.5912514', '35.594524', '-78.8117411', '-78.8064663'],
 'lat': '35.5928655',
 'lon': '-78.80864240000005',
 'display_name': 'School, Fuquay-Varina, Wake County, North Carolina, United States',
 'class': 'place',
 'type': 'neighbourhood',
 'importance': 0.36}
```

But I wanted to get list of possible result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the Taras's answer in [Get state but want country in GeoPy and Nominatim:](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/378947/get-state-but-want-country-in-geopy-and-nominatim/378977#378977)

> When you try embedding exactly_one=False parameter (by default it is True) into your code

And in [geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy.geocoders.Nominatim.geocode)

> geocode(query, *, **exactly_one=True**, timeout=DEFAULT_SENTINEL, limit=None, addressdetails=False, language=False, geometry=None, extratags=False, country_codes=None, viewbox=None, bounded=False, featuretype=None, namedetails=False)

Therefore:

```
location = geolocator.geocode("School") #= geolocator.geocode("School"), exactly_one=True)
print(location.raw)
{'place_id': 174509566, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 353533683, 'boundingbox': ['35.5912514', '35.594524', '-78.8117411', '-78.8064663'], 'lat': '35.5928655', 'lon': '-78.80864240000005', 'display_name': 'School, Fuquay-Varina, Wake County, North Carolina, United States', 'class': 'place', 'type': 'neighbourhood', 'importance': 0.36}
```

And

```
location = geolocator.geocode("School"), exactly_one=False)
for loc in location:
    print(loc.raw)
{'place_id': 174509566, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 353533683, 'boundingbox': ['35.5912514', '35.594524', '-78.8117411', '-78.8064663'], 'lat': '35.5928655', 'lon': '-78.80864240000005', 'display_name': 'School, Fuquay-Varina, Wake County, North Carolina, United States', 'class': 'place', 'type': 'neighbourhood', 'importance': 0.36}
{'place_id': 357867, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'node', 'osm_id': 151422297, 'boundingbox': ['36.9450563', '36.9850563', '-93.4874147', '-93.4474147'], 'lat': '36.9650563', 'lon': '-93.4674147', 'display_name': 'School, Stone County, Missouri, 65675, United States', 'class': 'place', 'type': 'hamlet', 'importance': 0.36, 'icon': 'https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/ui/mapicons//poi_place_village.p.20.png'}
{'place_id': 167700780, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 318165539, 'boundingbox': ['32.0714473', '32.0741895', '120.8146237', '120.8201063'], 'lat': '32.07294075', 'lon': '120.81740228211956', 'display_name': 'School, 唐闸镇街道, 崇川区, 南通市, 江苏省, 226000, 中国', 'class': 'landuse', 'type': 'construction', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
{'place_id': 215092800, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 602663948, 'boundingbox': ['37.0138617', '37.0150821', '26.9460925', '26.9465295'], 'lat': '37.0144836', 'lon': '26.9464163', 'display_name': 'School, Δήμος Καλυμνίων, Περιφερειακή Ενότητα Καλύμνου, Περιφέρεια Νοτίου Αιγαίου, Αποκεντρωμένη Διοίκηση Αιγαίου, 85200, Ελλάς', 'class': 'natural', 'type': 'cliff', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
{'place_id': 181158290, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 385516187, 'boundingbox': ['10.771975', '10.7722775', '79.7649394', '79.7653411'], 'lat': '10.7721123', 'lon': '79.7651351889881', 'display_name': 'School, Aliyur, Nagapattinam, Nagapattinam District, Tamil Nadu, India', 'class': 'natural', 'type': 'water', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
{'place_id': 209320653, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 578423904, 'boundingbox': ['28.1030218', '28.1035714', '82.2905674', '82.2914013'], 'lat': '28.1033061', 'lon': '82.29098062758565', 'display_name': 'School, Tarigaun, Tulsipur, दाङ देउखुरी, मध्य-पश्चिमाञ्चल विकास क्षेत्र, लुम्बिनी प्रदेश, नेपाल', 'class': 'landuse', 'type': 'residential', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
{'place_id': 168760433, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 319925177, 'boundingbox': ['20.7521232', '20.7529092', '-105.2560172', '-105.2553867'], 'lat': '20.752511849999998', 'lon': '-105.2557026180828', 'display_name': 'School, San Vicente, Bahía de Banderas, Nayarit, México', 'class': 'landuse', 'type': 'commercial', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
{'place_id': 218867956, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 624407053, 'boundingbox': ['7.480552', '7.4819875', '3.9080287', '3.909494'], 'lat': '7.4812069', 'lon': '3.908693944912778', 'display_name': 'School, Sasa Market, Akinyele, Oyo, Nigeria', 'class': 'landuse', 'type': 'commercial', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
{'place_id': 246268194, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 781113363, 'boundingbox': ['-13.6284285', '-13.6241848', '29.0467927', '29.0498197'], 'lat': '-13.626255950000001', 'lon': '29.048202796816035', 'display_name': 'School, Mkushi District, Central Province, Zambia', 'class': 'landuse', 'type': 'residential', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
{'place_id': 242730699, 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright', 'osm_type': 'way', 'osm_id': 778514086, 'boundingbox': ['-13.5496012', '-13.5475416', '28.9063684', '28.9090694'], 'lat': '-13.54840955', 'lon': '28.9077512070212', 'display_name': 'School, Mkushi District, Central Province, Zambia', 'class': 'landuse', 'type': 'commercial', 'importance': 0.30999999999999994}
```